# A question regarding limits and integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f\in L^{1}\left(\mathbb{R},m\right)$, where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.  I’m trying to prove that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}{\Big|f\left(x\right)-f\left(x+h\right)\Big|\hspace{3pt}dx}\right)}=0$.  I haven’t been able to get anywhere with it.  Any hints and/or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^1$. Can you prove this for this class of functions?

Comment: I presume that we are assuming the metric topology induced by the $L^1$ norm?

Comment: Yes, that is what he meant (presumably).

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: I’ve not seen that result, but I can [probably] prove it.

Comment: @anonymous : Hint : If you want to show that the continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^1(\mathbb R,m)$, start by showing that these functions can approximate characteristic functions of any measurable set $A$ (i.e. the function which is $1$ on $A$ and $0$ elsewhere). Since these characteristic functiosn are dense in $L^1$, you can conclude. To show that such an approximation exists, "trap" your set $A$ between a compact set (below) and an open set (above). This will help you construct the continuous function which will approximate the characteristic function of $A$.

Comment: Having proven that continuous compactly supported functions are dense in $L^1$, I suspect that I should approximate $f$ by such a function, say $\phi$, and observe that $\left\|\phi(x)-\phi\left(x+h\right)\right\|_1\rightarrow 0$ $\left(t\rightarrow 0\right)$ due to the continuity of $\phi$.  Is this correct?

Comment: Ive solved it.  Thanks for the hint.  It proved invaluable.